# Top views in scrollView are not visible in landscape screen

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

The problem is that in landscape screen position

I can't slide to see top textView.

And the image on the top is visible only partly.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/backNormal"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/backNormal"
            android:orientation="vertical"

        >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/backNormal"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            >


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/backNormal"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                  android:weightSum="6"
            >
        <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/backNormal"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_weight="4"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            >


        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNameTitle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text='Your profile'
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/text_style_title"
                />
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageNameAvatar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/clip32"
                />

                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editName"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        style="@style/edit_style"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textInfoGenderTitle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text='Gender'
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                style="@style/text_style_normal"
                />


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_gravity="center"
                      android:weightSum="4"
                >

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonInfoMale"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text='M'
                    style="@style/button_style_normal"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textInfoGender"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text='Unknown'
                    android:background="@color/backDark1"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonInfoFemale"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text='F'
                    style="@style/button_style_normal"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textInfoYearTitle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text='Year'
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                style="@style/text_style_normal"
                />


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_gravity="center"
                      android:weightSum="4"
                >
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonInfoYearMinus"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text='-'
                    style="@style/button_style_normal"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textInfoYear"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text='Unknown'
                    android:background="@color/backDark1"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonInfoYearPlus"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text='+'
                    style="@style/button_style_normal"
                    />


        </LinearLayout>


        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBarName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonNameReg"
                android:text='Registration'
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                style="@style/button_style_normal"
                />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNameResult"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=''
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/text_style_normal"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
        <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any advices please! Thanks!

Sorry for the text below.
The site said that my post is mostly code...
text text text text 
text text 
text text

Comment: post your complete layout file ?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot?